# Iterate through all RecordStore java me

Tags: java-me, midp, rms

How do I iterate through all recordstore for a j2me app?

The recordstore are created by the user when he enters some data.
So number of recordstore is not in my control.

**So does the app keep track of all recordstore associated with a j2me app?**
OR **should I create a recordStore that will contain name of all other recordstores?**

I can get all the row from a recordstore using

```
for(int i=1;i<=getnumrecords(RecordStoreName);i++)
RecordStoreName.getrecord(i);
```

**But I am looking for such functionality for getting all the recordstore name associated with my app.**

The reason I am creating a new RecordStore instead of a new row in one recordstore is because
the size of a recordstore in java me is limited by the phone.

So I have decided to create a new recordStore for every data I get from a form .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your user can remove entries from a `RecordStore` your loop will probably break because of an [`InvalidRecordIDException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/rms/InvalidRecordIDException.html) on the call to [`getRecord`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/rms/RecordStore.html#getRecord%28int%29).
A safer approach to iterate the records is to use a [`RecordEnumeration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/rms/RecordEnumeration.html):

```
RecordEnumeration re = RecordStoreName.enumerateRecords(null, null, false);

while (re.hasNextElement()) {
    RecordStoreName.getrecord(re.nextRecordId());
}
```

**Update after comments**

You can use `static` method [`listRecordStores`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/rms/RecordStore.html#listRecordStores%28%29). According to API:

> Returns an array of the names of record stores owned by the MIDlet
>   suite. Note that if the MIDlet suite does not have any record stores,
>   this function will return null. The order of RecordStore names
>   returned is implementation dependent.

Comment: No I was talking about dealing with RecordStore and not with record of a RecordStore. In example I shown that I can deal with records of a Recordstore, but I wanted to know how to deal with RecordStores like we deal with records..

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is provided for application developers with [RecordStore.listRecordStores](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/rms/RecordStore.html#listRecordStores%28%29) API:

> Returns an array of the names of record stores owned by the MIDlet suite. Note that if the MIDlet suite does not have any record stores, this function will return null. The order of RecordStore names returned is implementation dependent...